# WPF DataGrid Unable to bind from ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I've been looking at this for hours now but I cannot figure it out...
I have successfully bound "Questions" to the ItemsSource. Questions is a ObservableCollection containing QuestionVM objects.

For some reason the Text Column with the "Question" header cannot be bound to the Question property inside Questions.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuestion, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Question" Binding="{Binding Question}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Edit"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is part of the QuestionVM class with the properties.

```
public class QuestionVM
{
    private Question _question;
    public string Question { get { return _question.Question1; } set { _question.Question1 = value; } }
    public string Category { get { return _question.Category; } set { _question.Category = value; } }
    public ObservableCollection<AnswerVM> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I should be able to bind the Question property right? Why am I unable to do so?

EDIT:
Intellisense only shows the properties of the main data context and not the properties of the individual QuestionVMs inside the Questions ObservableCollection.

```
        DataContext="{Binding ExistingQuestions, Source={StaticResource Locator}}
```

ExistingQuestions contains the properties Questions, SelectedQuestion and AddQuestion. Those are the ones shown by Intellisense.

Pictures for further clarification:

[image: Attempting to bind..]

As you can see those are not the properties of QuestionVM but the main datacontext. It does not want to pick the properties from the ObservableCollection I've set as the ItemsSource.

[image: Properties of main data context.]

[image: I am trying to bind this property which is inside the QuestionVM.]

Comment: I don't think this is your issue, but `Question` being your primary backing type AND an important public property of your class is fairly confusing.  Consider `QuestionDTO` for the type?

Comment: Is Question a member of Questions? In that case the binding should be `Binding = {Binding Questions.Question}`.

Comment: @zzxyz I thought so too. Will most likely change it.

Comment: @fussel Question is a property inside the QuestionVM. The ItemsSource is bound to a ObservableCollection of QuestionVMs.

Comment: What do you mean with unable to bind? The `Question` is not displayed, or the value of it isn't updated, if you change it in ViewModel?

Comment: The Question is not displayed at all. Intellisense does not pick it up either. It only shows me the properties of the main data context to bind to.

Comment: @BobiSad That can happen sometimes and there is nothing you can do except file a bug report

Comment: Can you please show the code to which your DataContext refers. How and where is the resource `Locator` defined?

Comment: I somehow solved it now. I don't remember exactly what the cause was, but the Locator would always return a new VM. So if I wanted to use data of an existing VM it wouldn't work, since it returns a brand new one. I'm not sure if the bindings returned an error before but it doesn't now.

And the Intellisense problem is just Intellisense being stupid.

Answer (score -2):

Updated Answer

If an object does not appear in Intellisense, it may be due to the namespace where the object is created.
Make sure that the objects are declared in the same namespace or try to add the namespace of the object Question to the view.

Exemple of adding namespace to the view

```
xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:Mynamespace.Myclass"
```

Also, it appears that the viewmodel has not implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface which is used to notify the control's view when the binded property is updated.

Cordialement

Comment: Besides that it is nonsense to derive from DependencyObject, it is not the model, but the view model that should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Clemens With DependencyObject you are right, but it is no problem if a model implement INotifyPropertyChanged. It would be very rare but possible. Have a look at microsoft example application https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps/blob/master/src/BikeSharing.Clients.Core/Models/Rides/Ride.cs

Comment: @SirRufo Sure it's ok that a model implements INPC, but here it's more important that the view model does.